# InnoDB Deadlock History

Tags: mariadb, innodb, database-deadlocks

After a change in code, my database reports a lot of deadlock incidents, which are resolved after a while ( 1 < x < 5 minutes). I use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to view what happened but the information is not correct: statements and tables reported here are different from what I see in `INNODB_LOCKS` table (when it's not resolved yet).

The question is: How can I get a history, a log, of what deadlocks happened?  not just the most recent one.

Answer (score 1):

```
innodb_print_all_deadlocks = ON
```

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` is transient; the above should persist it by writing to a log file.

I recommend a few things to *decrease* the number of deadlocks:

- Do thing is the same order in different transactions.  This includes which rows are touched.
- Speed up the code.  (Better indexes, often 'composite', reformulate queries, etc)
- See if anything can reasonably be pulled out of the `BEGIN`...`COMMIT`.

For further discussion, please show us the SQL in a transaction, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.

In any case, test for errors throughout each transaction and be ready to replay when you hit a deadlock.

Note:  `lock_wait_timeout` is a related item.  It defaults to an unreasonably high 50 seconds.  If you raise that you are asking for more trouble.  Decreasing it (to, say, 5) is not a real solution, but it may change the problems in interesting ways.  Again, test for errors and react to them.  Hitting this "timeout" is as bad as a "deadlock".  Not hitting it, but waiting, is a silent way that InnoDB resolves conflicts successfully.